# Enabling Joomla anti copy right click .!

Tags: javascript, browser, joomla

There is a website on which right click and copy is disabled through joomla anti copy. I want to copy some text .I have tried

1. Disabling js through browser

But  it didn't work because the page is generated with js and if js is not working no content is generated.

2. `javascript:void(document.oncontextmenu=null);`

this one didn't help

3. using a proxy

which also didn't give results.
Any tip or advice is really appreciated .
Thanks in advance

Comment: Although it is not an answer there is no way you can stop a user from copying the content though you can disable right click. User can save the html as a file and open it in an editor. Your technique will work for dummies but it is a futile exercise and achieves nothing.

Comment: I do not want to restrict them  )) I want to get over of this functionality and copy the tet  I want

Comment: Terribly sorry on my part, I can be really an imbecile at times. I did not even read the question. Use Phantomjs to fetch the page and then evaluate the content. It is trivial and you can copy some code from its page. Save it as a file. You have the content.

Comment: why -1 ? ? ? I can not understand how this community works

Comment: Do not worry about that. Those votes have no significance, it just means that some people did not like your question possibly because they are smarter than you are. Try PhantomJS.

Comment: @Shiv that's not what the votes mean at all. The real meaning is that the question doesn't conform to site guidelines as oulined in [help] and is very incomplete

Comment: I do not know what those votes mean. Someone can downvote for any reason but I would consider it to be polite if people can punch in few keys about why they did that. Not that I expect that from someone because I am quite rude myself.

Comment: thanks @Shiv for advice , people who put -1 , yeah you are smarter and it is ok ))

Answer (score 0):

Key F12 >  Find your text > Edit as HTML > Copy.

Answer (score 0):

Just do inspect element find whatever you want to copy just copy it.